# How accurate is the Sudarsky Scale today?

Tags: exoplanet, jupiter, optics, planetary-formation, neptune

How accurate is the [Sudarsky scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sudarsky%27s_gas_giant_classification) of gas-giant classification today? Do the different classes still exist, and look roughly the same?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

The paper [Sudarsky et al., 2003](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2003ApJ...588.1121S/abstract), which the wikipedia article is based on, is probably outdated by now in two important aspects.
1.) They used equilibrium chemistry i.e. a local theory of perfect, uniform mixing in the entire atmosphere and infinitely fast chemistry. This has been by now realized to be important to correct ([e.g. Cooper&Showman 2006](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2006ApJ...649.1048C/abstract) or [Tsai et al. 2017](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017ApJS..228...20T/abstract)) and leads to different behaviour in the spectrum of a planet.

2.) The line-lists they used were inaccurate for many molecules for hot worlds ([see e.g. Tennyson & Yurchenko 2017](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2017MolAs...8....1T/abstract)), particularly in the infrared. This would mainly be leading to different computations of the P-T profile primarily, but that of course impacts the emission spectrum and hence the 'Sudarsky class'.

While those effects are impactful, I am not aware of any paper that systematically tried to redo the classification work from 2003, hence we don't know how impactful they would be overall.

Comment: Class-3 seems right at least, judging by that one exoplanet whose colour we know: https://exoplanets.nasa.gov/resources/139/nasas-hubble-finds-a-true-blue-planet/